How to override pgx/v5/pgtype with golang (go) native type
By default sqlc is converting my PostgreSQL column type temperature INT into Temperature pgtype.Int4.
This is my query:
CREATE TABLE weathers (
    temperature INT, 
);

And it generates:
package sql

import (
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgtype"
)

type Weather struct {
    Temperature pgtype.Int4
}

I want to use int instead of pgtype.Int4 for my Go struct.
According to the docs I can override this type.
I was able to convert by using the column value, but I wish to apply this to all columns of type integer.
In the docs they say Note that for Postgres you must use pg_catalog-prefixed names where available.
I looked into the link postgresql_type.go provided
So, I went to their source code and tried all the given options that can return a pgtype.Int4.
This is my sqlc.yaml with the values that I tried:
version: "2"
sql:
  - name: "sql"
    engine: "postgresql"
    queries: "query"
    schema: "migrate"
    gen:
      go:
        package: "sql"
        out: "sqlc"
        sql_package: "pgx/v5"
        overrides:
          - db_type: "pg_catalog.int4" # ❌ This does nothing
          # - db_type: "pg_catalog.int8" # ❌
          # - db_type: "pg_catalog.int" # ❌
          # - db_type: "pgtype.Int4" # ❌
          # - db_type: "pgtype.Int" # ❌
          # - db_type: "int4" # ❌
          # - db_type: "integer" # ❌
          # - db_type: "smallint" # ❌
          # - db_type: "bigint" # ❌
          # - db_type: "int" # ❌
          # - db_type: "int4range" # ❌
          # - db_type: "pg_catalog.numeric" # ❌
          # - db_type: "numeric" # ❌
            go_type:
              type:  "int"
          # - column: "weathers.temperature" # ✅ This works
          #   go_type:
          #     type:  "int"

How to override all pgtype.Int4 with native Go int?
Thanks,

This is my query: - is this your query or schema?

It works only in conjunction with nullable set to true:
overrides:
   - db_type: "pg_catalog.int4"
     nullable: true
     go_type:
       type:  "int"

Now after running sqlc generate I get:
// Code generated by sqlc. DO NOT EDIT.
// versions:
//   sqlc v1.27.0

package sql

type Weather struct {
        Temperature int
}

The
documentation
says:

nullable:
If true, sqlc will apply this override when a column is
nullable. Otherwise sqlc will apply this override when a column is
non-nullable. Note that this has no effect on column
overrides. Defaults to false.

